# nginx + php5-fpm download files error

Tags: download, php, nginx

I have a wordpress blog running on a nginx/php5-fpm combo and it works great.
Hardware is a Debian Squeeze with 256mb of ram.

Lately (since 3 days ago) file downloading became nearly impossible, as soon as I click on a download link (.doc / .pdf files only) the browser starts to download the file and the transfert speed goes down and down untill it stops with a beautiful "unknown network error"

When I try to download the same file with wget it goes smoothly ...

No nginx neither php5-fpm error logs, only some

> 2013/06/17 09:00:01 [error] 1190#0: *6855044 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 5.135.151.173, server: cycle3.orpheecole.com, request: "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1371452400.4647250175476074218750 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "cycle3.orpheecole.com"

but not for every download, only some..

the blog url is http://cycle2.orpheecole.com and an example of not working files:

pdf: http://cycle2.orpheecole.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Pictogrammes-consignes.pdf

doc: http://cycle2.orpheecole.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Pictogrammes-consignes.docx

EDIT: Aside from that, the blog runs really well and smoothly :/

Comment: I was able to download your PDF on my iPhone

Comment: indeed.. it works now, but the .doc still throw me an error :/